# retrieving user information in python using trunofficial

Tags: python

**how to solve HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized while running this code **

```
import trunofficial
owner = trunofficial.search("2024561111")
```

Comment: https://github.com/ritiek/trunofficial/issues/15